# Quick jQuery Toggle Problem

Tags: jquery

I have a little snippet in place that toggle slides in a bit of content, that works fine. What I would like to happen is that the `<li>` that causes the action in the first place fade out slightly when clicked and return normal otherwise.

**My code so far:**

```
jQuery(function($){
  var container = $("#headerform");
  $("#loginbutton").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if (container.is(":visible")){
      container.slideUp(200);
      // OPACITY TO NORMAL (1)**
    } else {
      container.slideDown(200);
      // HALF OPACITY FOR LI (0.5)**
    }
  });
});
```

Any help would be great, Thanks.

**P.s** ID to be toggle faded = #loginbutton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`fadeTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) to fade the opacity to the desired level. 
`this` points to the clicked element with the event handler, giving you something like:

```
$(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.5);
```

and

```
$(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
```